golang chan sender and receive queue sequence question
here is my code , why the answer is not sequence. GOMAXPROCS is 1 , and I'm confused why the first person to receive the message is the last Goroutine to join the queue !
I know in P > 1 example ,the result is unsequence because GMP schedule goroutinue with many threads.
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    c := make(chan struct{})
    ok := make(chan int)
    n := 10
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go foo(i, c, ok)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func() {
            <-c
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    close(ok)
}

func foo(i int, c chan struct{}, ok chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case c <- struct{}{}:
            fmt.Printf("%d sendMsg!\n", i)
        case <-ok:
            fmt.Printf("%d closed\n", i)
            return
        }
    }
}

the answer is below:
9 sendMsg!
0 sendMsg!
1 sendMsg!
2 sendMsg!
3 sendMsg!
4 sendMsg!
5 sendMsg!
6 sendMsg!
7 sendMsg!
8 sendMsg!

why is not sequence?

I know they will blocked in this case , and I make sleep after create customers . I try to sleep 1 second and 1 millisecond there, but the same result print.

The scheduler is free to choose one of the waiting goroutines, nothing more is specified to enable internal optimizations.
You have no other guarantees than the ones given by the Go memory model, so the order you are seeing is valid, but not guaranteed to be reproducible.
Why do you expect a certain order?

I run the code many times , and get the same result. I am confused by uncertain order by one P in GMP, I think they will be scheduled FIFO

You are running the code repeatedly under the same circumstances, on the same machine. The scheduler is free to choose whatever it thinks fits best to the current situation.
Keeping FIFO order is hard, because functions could be submitted concurrently. Even though they are not in your example, the scheduler has no incentive to try.
If you want FIFO order, don't depend on the scheduler.
